# How can I enable Caddy plugins in NixOS?

Tags: nix, nixos, caddy, nixpkgs

I've just started playing with NixOS, and have so far managed to edit `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` in my NixOS 18.09 VM to have PHP-FPM and the Caddy webserver enabled.

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  imports = [ <nixpkgs/nixos/modules/installer/virtualbox-demo.nix> ];

  users = {
    mutableUsers = false;
    groups = {
      caddy = { };
      php-project = { };
    };
    users = {
      hello = {
        group = "php-project";
      };
    };
  };

  environment.systemPackages = [
    pkgs.htop  
    pkgs.httpie
    pkgs.php  # for PHP CLI
  ];

  services.caddy = {
    enable = true;
    email = "david@example.com";
    agree = true;
    config = ''
      (common) {
        gzip
        header / -Server
        header / -X-Powered-By
      }
      :8080 {
        root /var/www/hello
        fastcgi / /run/phpfpm/hello.sock php
        log syslog
        import common
      }
    '';
  };

  services.phpfpm = {
    phpOptions = ''
      date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"
    '';
    poolConfigs = {
      hello = ''
        user = hello
        listen = /run/phpfpm/hello.sock
        ; ...
        pm.max_requests = 500
      '';
    };
  };
}
```

A PHP-processed response is available at at localhost:8080. (Yay!)

To [enable Caddy plugins when compiling from source](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/wiki/Plugging-in-Plugins-Yourself), Go imports are added to caddy's [run.go](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/blob/v0.11.0/caddy/caddymain/run.go#L39), e.g.:

```
_ "github.com/mholt/caddy/caddyhttp" // plug in the HTTP server type
    // This is where other plugins get plugged in (imported)
_ "github.com/nicolasazrak/caddy-cache" // added to use another plugin
)
```

How can I set such line insertion to be performed after the source is downloaded and before the build takes place? (If this is a reasonable approach when using Nix?)

[The NixOS 18.09 caddy package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-18.09/pkgs/servers/caddy/default.nix).

[The NixOS 18.09 caddy service](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-18.09/nixos/modules/services/web-servers/caddy.nix).

I believe that when writing a package a builder script (Bash or otherwise) can be assigned, and I'm thinking the line insertion could be done in it. But I'm lost as to how to assign a script to an existing package in this situation (override an attribute/use an overlay?) and where to put the script on the disk.

---

### Status update

I've been doing some reading on customising packages in general and it sounds like [overlays](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Overlays) might be what I need. However, I don't seem to be able to get my overlay evaluated.

I'm using overriding of the package name as a test as it's simpler than patching code.

#### Overlay attempt 1

`/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
{ config, pkgs, options, ... }:

{
  imports = [ <nixpkgs/nixos/modules/installer/virtualbox-demo.nix> ];

  nix.nixPath = options.nix.nixPath.default ++ [
    "nixpkgs-overlays=/etc/nixos/overlays-compat/"
  ];

  # ...
}
```

`/etc/nixos/overlays-compat/overlays.nix`:

```
self: super:
with super.lib;
let
  # Using the nixos plumbing that's used to evaluate the config...
  eval = import <nixpkgs/nixos/lib/eval-config.nix>;
  # Evaluate the config,
  paths = (eval {modules = [(import <nixos-config>)];})
    # then get the `nixpkgs.overlays` option.
    .config.nixpkgs.overlays
  ;
in
foldl' (flip extends) (_: super) paths self
```

`/etc/nixos/overlays-compat/caddy.nix`:

```
self: super:
{
  caddy = super.caddy.override {
    name = "caddy-override";
  };
}
```

### Overlay attempt 2

`/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
  nixpkgs.overlays = [ (self: super: {
    caddy = super.caddy.override {
      name = "caddy-override";
    };
  } ) ];
```

`error: anonymous function at /nix/store/mr5sfmz6lm5952ch5q6v49563wzylrkx-nixos-18.09.2327.37694c8cc0e/nixos/pkgs/servers/caddy/default.nix:1:1 called with unexpected argument 'name', at /nix/store/mr5sfmz6lm5952ch5q6v49563wzylrkx-nixos-18.09.2327.37694c8cc0e/nixos/lib/customisation.nix:69:12`

### overrideAttrs

I previously managed to override the package name with this:

```
{ config, pkgs, options, ... }:

let
  caddyOverride = pkgs.caddy.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec {
    name = "caddy-override-v${oldAttrs.version}";
  });
in {
{
  # ...

  services.caddy = {
    package = caddyOverride;
    # ...
  }
}
```

I could see in htop that the caddy binary was in a folder called `/nix/store/...-caddy-override-v0.11.0-bin/`. But I understand that overriding in this way has been superseded by overlays.

Comment: Overlays are for modifying the `pkgs` variable, but that's not necessary because you can already put an arbitrary derivation in `services.caddy.package`. What I can see is mostly plumbing to get your overlays from the `nixpkgs.overlays` option to other places like the `NIX_PATH` environment variable, but I don't see how you define the overlay in `nixpkgs.overlays`.

Comment: I understood from the wiki and other pages that all overlay files in the given directory would be used. My idea was to do something like adding a 'patches' attribute to the package via overrideAttrs or an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add plugins to Caddy, it seems that [the method](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/wiki/Plugging-in-Plugins-Yourself) is to modify the source.

You will need to adapt the Nixpkgs [expression for Caddy](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/e23580caf869ddab80c0fe99cffe399790cf3203/pkgs/servers/caddy/default.nix) to make that possible. That can be done outside the Nixpkgs tree, using `services.caddy.package = callPackage ./my-caddy.nix {}` for example, or by forking the Nixpkgs repository and pointing your `NIX_PATH` to your clone.

Comment: Thanks! Re. modify source: indeed. Re. fork and modify expression: ah, so a fork is definitely necessary, and I can't "extend" the expression with an overlay? If so, should this be done with 'patches = [ /path/to/patch ]' in my fork?

Comment: Sorry for the mixed signals. I usually fork so I can upstream the code easily, but you can use overlays or `services.caddy.package` instead.

Comment: Patches are useful for this. Alternatively you can use the `postPatch` attribute to modify the sources with a script.

Comment: Simply modifying the `preBuild` function is not enough to bring in the dependencies into Caddy. You have to also update the `go-modules` derivation to add in the extra plugin as a dependency. However this is documented anywhere and I've not been successful in https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/14671

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue for Caddy plugins: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/14671

PR welcome!